# How can I test whether a Java collection supports the add operation?

Tags: java

In Java, whether a `Collection` support `add` depends on the concrete class.
Say I have code like:

```
List<String> otherNames = getOthers();
names.add(myName);
```

The second line will raise `UnsupportedOperationException` if the underlying List don't support this, one common example is `Collections.emptyList()`.

Of course, we can create a new list to hold the content, but I wonder is there is way to test the list?

Comment: one way is to catch that exception and deal with it if it occurs. It's not that the method doesn't exist. It does, but it throws the UnsupportedOperationException so you can't use reflection because it's actually a method.

Comment: The only way to know that without actually trying to invoke that method is to inspect bytecode of this method implementation and find out whether it consists of a single throw instruction (along with creating exception object). That would be a tricky approach and you should not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure it's mutable, you can always just defensively copy the list.

```
List<String> otherNames = new ArrayList<>(getOthers());
names.add(myName);
```

If your lists are really big, or are part of a tight loop, then you could write a method which checks the type of the list before committing to a copy, so that you don't copy an already mutable list unnecessarily.

```
static <T> List<T> copyIfMaybeImmutable(List<T> list) {
    //expand condition as required, e.g. CopyOnWriteArrayList
    if (!(otherNames instanceof ArrayList) && !(otherNames instanceof LinkedList)) {
        return new ArrayList<>(list);
    }
    return list;
}
```

(It's not possible to be comprehensive, since many methods will use anonymous or private List implementations, but there is still performance to be gained by supporting the common cases)

Use like

```
List<String> otherNames = copyIfMaybeImmutable(getOthers());
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. I currently use the defensively copy approach. I think it's better design if the List interface have a method like `boolean supportAdd()`.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of `add` exists. It's just that its implementation throws the exception. That means the only way to know is to try and catch that exception. The implementation of `EmptyList.add` is this:

```
public void add(E var1) {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Using reflection to see if an `add` method exists will not tell you what you want to know because it's a perfectly valid method. Instead you need to call it and catch the exception like this:

```
try {
  otherNames.add(myName);
} catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
  // whatever you want in this case (create a copy into a Vector, etc)
  overflowList.add(myName);
}
```

For example you could have a `Vector` (called `overflowList` in my example) that you add any things you couldn't add to the actual list and deal with them at the end.